# xslt to transform xml with global element at start

Tags: xml, dom, xslt, xpath, fixed-width

I have an xml file with the below structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <VocaDocument xmlns:cmn="http://www.voca.com/schemas/common" xmlns:me="http://www.voca.com/schemas/messaging">
  <Data>
      <Document>
          <StreamStart>
              <Stream>
                  <BankName>LLOYDS BANK PLC</BankName> 
                  <BankCode>0004</BankCode> 
                  <StreamCode>01</StreamCode> 
                  <VoucherSortCode>SC987654</VoucherSortCode> 
                  <VoucherAccountNumber>99775533</VoucherAccountNumber> 
              </Stream>
          </StreamStart>
          <DDIVouchers>
              <Voucher>
                  <TransactionCode>NEW</TransactionCode> 
                  <OriginatorIdentification>
                      <ServiceUserName>A CUSTOMER</ServiceUserName> 
                      <ServiceUserNumber>123456</ServiceUserNumber> 
                  </OriginatorIdentification>
                  <PayingBankAccount>
                      <BankName>A BANK LTD</BankName> 
                      <AccountName>A PERSON</AccountName> 
                      <AccountNumber>99887766</AccountNumber> 
                      <UkSortCode>SC123456</UkSortCode> 
                  </PayingBankAccount>
                  <ReferenceNumber>BACS1234567</ReferenceNumber> 
                  <ContactDetails>
                      <PhoneNumber>020 83395862</PhoneNumber> 
                      <FaxNumber /> 
                      <Address>
                          <cmn:AddresseeName>A NAME</cmn:AddresseeName> 
                          <cmn:PostalName>A CUSTOMER</cmn:PostalName> 
                          <cmn:AddressLine>Line 1</cmn:AddressLine> 
                          <cmn:TownName>Town</cmn:TownName> 
                          <cmn:CountyIdentification /> 
                          <cmn:CountryName>UNITED KINGDOM</cmn:CountryName> 
                          <cmn:ZipCode>AA1 4AB</cmn:ZipCode> 
                      </Address>
                  </ContactDetails>
                  <ProcessingDate>2014-08-19</ProcessingDate> 
                  <BankAccount>
                      <FirstLastVoucherCode>FirstLast</FirstLastVoucherCode> 
                      <AgencyBankCode>0123</AgencyBankCode> 
                      <SortCode>SC654321</SortCode> 
                      <AccountNumber>12345678</AccountNumber> 
                      <TotalVouchers>1</TotalVouchers> 
                      <Counter /> 
                  </BankAccount>
              </Voucher>
```

what I need to do is output the data in fixed length text format, one line for each of the *Voucher* elements with the *Stream* elements at the start of each line.

so it should look something like the below in the output file (that will be loaded up into the AS400 accounting system):

```
LLOYDS BANK PLC                                                       00040001SC9876549977553300000000NEW       A CUSTOMER                           123456A BANK                                                                            A PERSON ...
```

So, my question is: how could I match each *Voucher* record and put the *Stream* record at the start of each record - do I need to use a variable to store the values in the *Stream* element?

Once I have done that I can look into using concat with substring to maybe pad leading spaces into the output as I have see in [SO 16816251: xml-to-fixed-width-text-file-with-xsl-style-sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816251/xml-to-fixed-width-text-file-with-xsl-style-sheet)

Thanks for any suggestions or tips

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. It seems you have already found the answer to producing fixed-width text format.

Comment: sorry, maybe I need to clarify it. I don't know how to output one line for each *voucher* element with the *stream* element at the start of the line.

Comment: That has nothing to do with fixed-width and everything to do with navigating the XML input document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, let us take a *minimal, but complete* example of XML **input**:

```
<VocaDocument>
  <Data>
      <Document>
          <StreamStart>
              <Stream>
                  <BankName>LLOYDS BANK PLC</BankName> 
              </Stream>
          </StreamStart>
          <DDIVouchers>
              <Voucher>
                  <TransactionCode>NEW</TransactionCode> 
                  <OriginatorIdentification>
                      <ServiceUserNumber>123456</ServiceUserNumber> 
                  </OriginatorIdentification>
               </Voucher>              
               <Voucher>
                  <TransactionCode>OLD</TransactionCode> 
                  <OriginatorIdentification>
                      <ServiceUserNumber>789012</ServiceUserNumber> 
                  </OriginatorIdentification>
               </Voucher>
          </DDIVouchers>
      </Document>
  </Data>
</VocaDocument>
```

Next, consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="VocaDocument/Data/Document/DDIVouchers/Voucher">
        <xsl:value-of select="../../StreamStart/Stream/BankName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="TransactionCode" />
        <xsl:value-of select="OriginatorIdentification/ServiceUserNumber" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result here will be:

```
LLOYDS BANK PLCNEW123456
LLOYDS BANK PLCOLD789012
```

### Explanation:

The instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="VocaDocument/Data/Document/DDIVouchers/Voucher">
```

puts us in the context of `Voucher`. In this context, the path:

```
"../../StreamStart/Stream/BankName"
```

goes "up" to the parent element twice (i.e. to `Document`) and from there "down" to `StreamStart/Stream/BankName` where the required value is.

---

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="BankName" select="VocaDocument/Data/Document/StreamStart/Stream/BankName" />
    <xsl:for-each select="VocaDocument/Data/Document/DDIVouchers/Voucher">
        <xsl:value-of select="$BankName" />
        <xsl:value-of select="TransactionCode" />
        <xsl:value-of select="OriginatorIdentification/ServiceUserNumber" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem of padding the individual values is left as an exercise for the reader (who has already found the solution).

Comment: what a perfectly complete answer, thank you for taking the time to help me, I was kind of floundering in the dark!

Comment: The carriage return isn't working, and when I run it I only get the Stream once.